# Heroku crashed when following Basic Auth example on Plotly Dash website

Tags: authentication, heroku, plotly-dash

After following the [Deploying Dash Apps](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment) on Heroku example, I then changed app.py to the [Basic Auth Example](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication) on the Plotly Dash website. My Heroku site then crashed as a result. How do I make the example work on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the Heroku logs, I found two errors:

1. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2. Failed to find attribute 'server' in 'app'.

I installed the requests library, making sure to update requirements.txt. (Not sure if this step was necessary, but it was the first error I fixed.) In the [Basic Auth Example](https://dash.plotly.com/authentication), you will notice `server = app.server` is not present, but is present in [Deploying Dash Apps](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment). Once I added the server info, everything worked:

```
    app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
    server = app.server
```